# Getting error no applicable method for 'as.raster' applied to an object of class "shiny.tag"

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R and am trying to render different images onto a ggplot in shiny based on user inputs. The following code is proving troublesome:

```
    myimg <- tags$div(tags$img(src = "myimg.png"))

    mygrid <- grid::rasterGrob(myimg, interpolate = TRUE)

    mydata %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_blank() +
    annotation_custom(mygrid, -3, 3, -3, 3)
```

Specifically, grid::rasterGrob(myimg, interpolate = TRUE)
is returning the error "no applicable method for 'as.raster' applied to an object of class "shiny.tag"" when I run the app and attempt to view the plot. If I run the code outside of shiny, it produces the raster and I have no problem calling it in annotation_custom() and the plot will work in shiny.

I can't seem to find anything on Google about this error, but if this has been covered elsewhere, I apologize. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here or how all this gits into a shiny app. Functions like `tags$div` and `tags$img` only return HTML tags. They don't contain any image data. You still need to load data and pass it into `rasterGrob` if you want to actually work with it in code.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I was told by a colleague that png::readPNG would not work in Shiny and that I would have to use tags, which I am unfamiliar with, in order to get images from the working directory. What I am trying to do is take a collection of .png files that are essentially combinations of shapes and allow users to create an arrangement of those shapes based on the inputs. Take for example: myshapesV1 <- gsub(" ", "", input$myinput)
myshapesV2 <- paste0(myshapesV1, ".png")                          
myshapesV3 <- tags$div(tags$img(src = myshapesV2)).

Comment: MrFlick, your suggestion helped. I found out that I had mistakenly saved my .R file containing the shiny script to a different folder than the images I was trying to load in. Once I relocated the R. file, readPNG worked fine. Thank you for getting me going in the right direction.